# Express.js serving generated index.html issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router

I am right now working on a dummy project to learn express and webpack with react and react router, I want to redirect all of my server requests to index.html so I won't get "Cannot GET" errors when accessing different URLs. Right now I am in development mode and the problem is I am serving generated HTML using HtmlWebpackPlugin. I tried this code, but all I get is "ENOENT" errors when accessing any URL except the root one.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'), function(err) {
       if (err) {
           res.status(500).send(err);
       }
   });
});
```

Here's also my webpack.config :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './client/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                test: /\.css$/,
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'client/index.html',
            fileName: path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'),
        }),
    ],
};
```

Is it possible to solve this issue by using express?

P.S. Also can someone explain why does server loads generated index.html normally when accessing root URL. I thought I am intercepting all my requests with the code snippet above. Really confused right now

Here's my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const models = require('./models');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const schema = require('./schema/schema');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();    
const MONGO_URI = 'some_uri';    
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => console.log('Connected to MongoLab instance.'))
    .on('error', error => console.log('Error connecting to MongoLab:', 
error));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    '/graphql',
    expressGraphQL({
        schema,
        graphiql: true,
    })
);

const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js');
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'), 
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } 
        });
```

Here's package.json, I am using older versions of some packages because I am following the tutorial, plan to update them later though:

```
{
  "name": "graphql-learning-project-02",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js --ignore client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-client": "^0.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.0",
    "graphql": "^0.8.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.8",
    "nodemon": "*",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-apollo": "^0.9.0",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire express main file? It's hard to tell if there are other conflicts causing this behavior without seeing it. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeAbeln hey i am gonna post it later today, but right now i don't have access to the code, i remember using webpack middleware, maybe its responsible for some of the behavior of the sever.

Comment: Yes it is possible but we need to see your server js configuration. Also, could it be possible for you to post your package.json so we can see which packages you have available and which versions?

Comment: @c-chavez hey i updated description with server.js and package.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) middleware to always fallback to index.html. This can be used in both dev and prod environments.

Use it like this:

```
const connectHistoryApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

...

app.use(connectHistoryApiFallback({
  verbose: false
}));

// static files and folders must be set after connectHistoryApiFallback
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(app.get('port'), (err) => {
  console.info('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) is not generating any files.
It means no `index.html` is generated.

According to [its documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF0Uz.png):

> No files are written to disk, rather it handles files in memory

Please remove:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => { ...
```

To server webpack files in the development mode:

```
app.use('*', webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)))
```

`app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html') ...` can be used after production webpack build.

Comment: oh i see that explains how it can serve index.html when accessing root url, but i still can't redirect to in memory index.html when accessing any other url (for example http://127.0.0.1:4000/list i get "Cannot GET /list").
Also when i used `app.use('*', webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)))`, i got syntax error in console saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (bundle.js 1).
It only works when i replace '*' with '/' but then no redirect is happening from other url which is my main goal :(.

Comment: The explanation makes sense but I tried it and all I get are errors because the page can't load js chunks when accessing a route like /dashboard/results. I am trying to find a way to use react-router with express and webpack-dev-middleware while avoiding accessing the index.html built in production which by the way is not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still experiencing this issue, you are mostly using **express** with **webpack-dev-middleware** and **react-router** just like me.

I found a solution when using the latest updates of the packages.

You can notice in webpack-dev-middleware documentation that [writeToDisk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk) option is set to **false** by default. Just set it to **true** while still sending the index.html file located in your build folder.

For those of you also needing a proxy to use a REST api on localhost:80, here's the server script I came up with :

```
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config';
import proxy from 'express-http-proxy';

global.watch = true;

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const app = express();
const getPath = req => require('url').parse(req.url).path;
const createProxy = ({ hostname = 'localhost', path = '' }) => proxy(hostname, { proxyReqPathResolver: req => `${path}${getPath(req)}` });

export default async () => {

  // Webpack dev Server
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    writeToDisk: true,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: webpackConfig.stats,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }))

  // Hot module replacement
  .use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

  // Proxy
  .use('/api', createProxy({ path: '/api' }))
  .use('/auth', createProxy({ path: '/auth' }))

  // Static path
  .use(express.static(webpackConfig.output.path))

  // Handles routes
  .get('/*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(webpackConfig.output.path + '/index.html');
  })

  // Start
  .listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.info('Listening to http://localhost:3000');
    }
  });
};
```

I am using babel-node to run the scripts so use **require** instead of **import** if using node.